# R: RPushbullet error when running pbGetDevices() on a Windows 11 machine

Tags: r, json, package

I am trying to install the `RPushbullet` package on a Windows 11 machine. I am using `R 4.1.1`. I have created the `json` file and I placed it in the `$HOME` directory. But when I am running the command `fromJSON(pbGetDevices())$devices[,c("iden", "nickname")]` I am receiving the following error: Error: ***Argument 'txt' must be a JSON string, URL or file***. The .rpushbullet.json file in my `$HOME` directory has the correct API key, devices and names written in it. When I installed the package on a Windows 10 machine I encountered no problems. Here is the code:

```
install.packages("RPushbullet")
library(RPushbullet)
library(jsonlite)

#here is created the json file using Sys.getenv("HOME") in order to find the $HOME directory. The json file has the following code written:
{
    "key": "my api",
    "devices": [],
    "names": []
}

pbSetup()

#after excecuting the pbSetup(), the key, devices and names filled with the correct text

fromJSON(pbGetDevices())$devices[,c("iden", "nickname")] #here I am getting the error mentioned in the description
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to run `fromJSON(pbGetDevices())$devices[,c("iden", "nickname")]` in order to start receiving notifications in your phone. I couldn't use the `pbPost` command because I was using double quotes ("") in the arguments instead of single one (''). For example:

```
pbPost("note", "check", "test") #this is wrong
pbPost('note', 'check', 'test') #this works
```